# How can I "refresh" or "update" the datatable object/widget so that it recognizes the new cell values?

Tags: jquery, datatables

**The scenario:**

A new row is added to the table and exposes the cells as empty input fields to the user (i.e., "inline" editing) - looks like this...
i.e.,

[image]

Then the user enters data in the input fields - looks like this...
i.e.,

[image]

When the user clicks the "Done" button, I transform the input fields to plain text, reflecting the value entered - looks like this...
i.e.,

[image]

Note how - visually - the table appears "updated"... -But,  when I use the "row().data()" function to reveal the row contents, there are no values associated with the cells.

[image]

So, I can see that I have not communicated to the "datatables" object that the row's cell values have changed.  -But, its clear that the table/html does contain the new cell values.

**QUESTION:  How can I "refresh" or "update" the datatable object/widget so that it recognizes the new values?**

*(NOTE: I'd like to accomplish this using the new API - but, the documentation is not clear enough for me to understand how)*

Thanks for any help!

---

***Below, is the complete jquery/javascript - if you think it might be helpful...***

```
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    var $contextPath;

    jq(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
        $contextPath = jq("#contextPath").val();

        jq('table').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();        

            //...collect the clicked "tag name" and use it to determine what to do...
            var tagName = e.target.tagName;

            if (tagName === "BUTTON")
            {
                if (jq(e.target).html()=== 'Edit')
                {
                    //...get list of previous "sibling" td's...
                    var editCellList = jq(e.target).parent().prevAll();

                    //...iterate over list and replace plain html text with "input" tag - use plain html text as initial value...                
                    editCellList.each(function(e)
                    {
                        jq(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + jq(this).html() + "' />");
                    });

                    //...change/toggle the button title from "Edit" to "Save"... 
                    jq(e.target).html('Done');
                }
                else
                {   
                    //...change/toggle the button title from "Save" to "Edit"...                 
                    jq(e.target).html('Edit');

                    //...get list of previous "sibling" td's...                
                    var saveCellList = jq(e.target).parent().prevAll();

                    //...iterate over list and convert "input" tag value to plain html text...                    
                    saveCellList.each(function(e)
                    {
                        jq(this).html(jq(this).find(">:first-child").val());
                    });

                    jq(this).draw();
                }
            }
        });

        jq("#submitForm").click(function () {
            alert(JSON.stringify(jq("#page0Form").serialize()));
            jq.post("page0/submitForm", jq("#page0Form").serialize());
        });

        //...just  hardcoded this button as a test to "see" the contents of the new row..
        jq("#gridDataTest").click(function () {
            var d = page0grid.row(2).data();
            alert(JSON.stringify(d));
        });

        var page0grid = jq('#page0grid').DataTable({
            "ajax": $contextPath + "/page0/testGridList",
            "columns": [
                {"title": "ID",      "data": "id",          "visible": false    },          
                {"title": "Field A", "data": "fieldAStrg"                       },
                {"title": "Field B", "data": "fieldBStrg"                       }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 3,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button class='edit'>Edit</button>"
                }],
            "info": false,
            "searching": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "scrollY": 600,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "order": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
            "bSort": false
        });

        jq('#addNew').click(function () {

            var buttonTitleArray = jq('#page0grid tbody > tr > td > button').map(function(){
                return jq(this).html();
            }).get();

            if(jq.inArray("Done", buttonTitleArray )===-1)
            {
                var pos = jq('#page0grid tbody > tr').length;
                var rowNode = page0grid.row.add(
                {
                    "id":"",
                    "fieldAStrg":"", 
                    "fieldBStrg":""
                }, pos).draw().node(); 

                jq(rowNode).find("button").trigger("click");
            }
        });

    });
```

***Below, is the JSP file, if you think it will help (not using any of the taglibs, obviously)...***

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c"        uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="form"     uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="spring"   uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="fmt"      uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>  

    <form id="page0Form" >

        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
                <h6 class='panel-title'>page0grid</h6>
            </div>    
            <div class='panel-body table-responsive' style='padding:0;'>    
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="page0grid"></table>
            </div>
        </div>         

        <button type="button" id="addNew" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>
        <button type="button" id="gridDataTest" class="btn btn-success">TEST</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Try using `object.append()` instead of `object.html()`, so you simply... well... append rows to your table instead of replacing the whole code (which, not surprisingly, removes event handlers used by jQuery, as it is completely new code -even if it's exactly the same HTML-). http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: thx Alejandro!!  - I'll give that a shot tomorrow and let you know.   -And, thank you again for taking time to respond!

Comment: -fwiw, I'm using .html() to change the cell content from <input/>  to text (after user makes an entry).  I assume your suggestion applies still?  (your example was citing adding rows)... just want to be clear

Comment: **Everything** that you are modifying using `html()` is new in the document. If you have this: `<block1>hehe</block1>` and you do `$("block1").html('hehe');` what you are doing is: 1. Set `block1` inner HTML to be null (thus deleting all inside it). 2. Setting `block1` inner HTML to be "hehe" (thus creating a completely new "hehe" string). It's the same text, but a **different** element for the DOM.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro.   That will be helpful to know that in the near future.  If you get opportunity , let me know how you might improve my solution (below).   -Thanks again!!!

Comment: Sorry, I never used jQuery DataTables, so I can't help you. It was a recommendation for the future though :) good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I arrived at (after some clawing and scratching) - you can compare to the corresponding code above to see what I changed...

Could be considered a hack, I suppose (I am not a datatables expert) - but, it seems to work adequately...
(of course, any, advice on making it more elegant, efficient, etc is welcome)

Thanks again for all who read and responded to my post!

```
    -
    -
    -
    else
    {   
        //...change/toggle the button title from "Save" to "Edit"...                 
        jq(e.target).html('Edit');

        //...get list of previous "sibling" td's...                
        var saveCellList = Array.prototype.reverse.call(jq(e.target).parent().prevAll());    //...to reverse order?...               

        var ri = jq(e.target).closest("tr").index();

        for (i=0;i<saveCellList.length;i++)
        {
            var cv =jq(saveCellList[i]).find(">:first-child").val();
            dt.cell(ri, i+1).data(cv);
        }

        jq(this).DataTable().draw();
    }
    -
    -
    -
```

[image]

---

### If you find it would be helpful, below, is the entire javascript...

```
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    var $contextPath;

    jq(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

        $contextPath = jq("#contextPath").val();

        jq('table').click(function(e) {

            var dt = jq(this).DataTable();
            e.preventDefault();        

            //...collect the clicked "tag name" and use it to determine what to do...
            var tagName = e.target.tagName;

            if (tagName === "BUTTON")
            {
                if (jq(e.target).html()=== 'Edit')
                {
                    //...get list of previous "sibling" td's...
                    var editCellList = jq(e.target).parent().prevAll();

                    //...iterate over list and replace plain html text with "input" tag - use plain html text as initial value...                
                    editCellList.each(function(e)
                    {
                        jq(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + jq(this).html() + "' />");
                    });

                    //...change/toggle the button title from "Edit" to "Save"... 
                    jq(e.target).html('Done');
                }
                else
                {   
                    //...change/toggle the button title from "Save" to "Edit"...                 
                    jq(e.target).html('Edit');

                    //...get list of previous "sibling" td's...                
                    var saveCellList = Array.prototype.reverse.call(jq(e.target).parent().prevAll());    //...to reverse order?...               

                    var ri = jq(e.target).closest("tr").index();

                    for (i=0;i<saveCellList.length;i++)
                    {
                        var cv =jq(saveCellList[i]).find(">:first-child").val();
                        dt.cell(ri, i+1).data(cv);
                    }

                    jq(this).DataTable().draw();
                }
            }
        });


        jq("#submitForm").click(function () {
            alert(JSON.stringify(jq("#page0Form").serialize()));
            jq.post("page0/submitForm", jq("#page0Form").serialize());
        });

        jq("#gridDataTest").click(function () {
            var d = page0grid.row(2).data();
            alert(JSON.stringify(d));
        });


        var page0grid = jq('#page0grid').DataTable({
            "ajax": $contextPath + "/page0/testGridList",
            "columns": [
                {"title": "ID",      "data": "id",          "visible": false    },          
                {"title": "Field A", "data": "fieldAStrg"                       },
                {"title": "Field B", "data": "fieldBStrg"                       }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 3,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button class='edit'>Edit</button>"
                }],
            "info": false,
            "searching": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "scrollY": 600,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "order": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
            "bSort": false
        });

        jq('#addNew').click(function () {


            var buttonTitleArray = jq('#page0grid tbody > tr > td > button').map(function(){
                return jq(this).html();
            }).get();

            if(jq.inArray("Done", buttonTitleArray )===-1)
            {
                var rowIndex = jq('#page0grid tbody > tr').length;
                console.log("row index(?)...:[" + rowIndex + "]"); 

                var rowNode = page0grid.row.add(
                {
                    "id": "NEW" + jq.now(),
                    "fieldAStrg":"", 
                    "fieldBStrg":""
                }, rowIndex).draw().node(); 

                console.log("addNew...row data at index rowIndex=" + page0grid.cell(rowIndex,0).data());            

                jq(rowNode).find("button").trigger("click");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your solution boils down to essentially  the same thing as mine: Update the data using `.data()`, which can be called on `table`, `rows`, `row`, or `cell`. Then call `.draw()` to update the display.  The rest is just preparing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the changed data to [`row().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())

```
var tr = jq(e.target).closest("tr");
var saveCellList = jq(e.target).parent().prevAll();

page0grid.row(tr).data(saveCellList.map(function() {
    return jq(this).find(">:first-child").val();
}).get()).draw();
```

Comment: Hi Gilly... thanks for the help...   When I replace:   saveCellList.each(function(e)
{
 jq(this).html(jq(this).find(">:first-child").val());
});    ...with:                    var activeTR = jq(e.target).closest("tr");
                jq(this).DataTable().row(activeTR).data(saveCellList.map(function (e)
                {
                     return jq(this).find(">:first-child").val();
                })).draw();  .... the data appears to persist... but the cells show "null".

Comment: @sairn - I answered in a hurry and left syntax errors (missing paren and `return` statement). Plus I forgot to call `.get()`. Sorry about that.  I've corrected my answer, but I'm using my phone, so I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thx, gilly3 -  I like your idea (always looking for smaller, more elegant solutions) -  but, I could not get it to work.  Got this error:  "DataTables warning: table id=page0grid - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 2...[etc]..".